# which version of openGL I can use?

Tags: opengl, x11, putty, glx, x11-forwarding

I am trying to execute openGL program(specifically gazebo) on remote ubuntu server with putty and Xming Server. I use Xming cause VNC does not support OpenGL. (Related : [How can I run an OpenGL application installed on a linux machine from my windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106201/how-can-i-run-an-opengl-application-installed-on-a-linux-machine-from-my-windows))

Now I want to check which version of OpenGL local machine(Windows 7) has.

I did it by twofold way.

First, I executed OpenGL Extension viewer and it said I have 4.2 version

Second, I executed putty by typing 'putty.exe -ssh -X ' on my local's command line(cmd).

And there, I saw the output of glxinfo.

it said

```
OpenGL vender string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string : Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
OpenGL core profile version string: 1.2 (4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.4226)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.4226)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Above when I run Xming and below when I run Xming-mesa:

```
OpenGL vender string: Mesa project: www.mesa3d.org
OpenGL renderer string : Mesa GLX Indirect
OpenGL core profile version string: 1.2 (1.5 Mesa 6.4.1)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (1.5 Mesa 6.4.1)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Which version of OpenGL I can use with Xming server? version 4.2 OpenGL or 1.2 OpenGL?

In fact, I really need high version of OpenGL to execute gazebo

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The Intel HD Graphics 4600 is a newer graphics chip, so it should be able to run version 4.2, which then automatically means it should support 1.2 as well.