# Run visual simulation from OpenGL running on Ubuntu terminal from Windows

Tags: opengl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glut, glew, bullet

I built a simulation code using OpenGL X11 GLUT GLEW and bullet-physics on Linux. The code and the visuals run really nicely on a pure Linux environment.

Now, I built the code on a windows machine using an Ubuntu terminal (downloaded from Microsoft Store). When I run the code, I get a `cannot connect to X server` message

After some reading, I found (and learned) that on Windows you could install *Xming* as the visualization server, while exporting `DISPLAY=localhost:0` on the Linux side. After doing this, I get the message: `No appropriate visual found`

How can I solve this? I tried what this question mentions: [How can I run an OpenGL application installed on a linux machine from my windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106201/how-can-i-run-an-opengl-application-installed-on-a-linux-machine-from-my-windows), but on the *Putty* section I got lost. If somebody could list some specific steps, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you need both X11 and GLUT? If you get rid of X11, compiling and running your code natively for windows (without WSL) will be easy (no need to install X server). You can even use MSYS2 to get mostly the same environment you had on Ubuntu (bash, GCC, and what not).

Comment: I would not like to refactor the code at this point, and I think that some dependencies are not windows compatible. It would be great if anybody could provide a recipe for using an X server

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have a X server nor client. You have several options:

- Install a X server and client for Windows.
- Run the program on Linux and connect to it via a X client for Windows.
- Replace the X11 code with Windows code.
- Use a library that abstracts you from details such as SDL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. At this point, I would not like to refactor the code, so I think I will go for the 1st and/or 2nd options you mention. Could you provide a list of steps to follow for achieving this?

Comment: @learning_dude You're welcome! That all depends on the software you end up using (AFAIK there are few tools, commercial and/or FOSS). I suggest reading the manuals of whatever tools you choose and opening new questions regarding them.